# dumpe the undefined hash value into yaml

Tags: perl

I am going to create yaml file by dumping hash values to a file. But if the value is undefined its printing `~`. I need to print `nill` if value is undefined. Which variable I need to set to get the undefined value as `Nill`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML qw(Dump Bless);

my $a=1;
my $b;
my $hash = { a => $a,b => $b };
open(FH,">file.yaml") or die "Can't open file.yaml: $!";
print FH Dump($hash);
close FH;
```

I need output as

```
a : 1
b : Nill
```

but its printing

```
a : 1
b : ~
```

Comment: *"I need to print nill if value is undefined"*  I think you should explain this as it could be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Neither `nill` nor `Nill` have any meaning to [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) except as a string, so YAML isn't going to generate either for `undef`. If you want the output to include `nill` or `Nill`, it will need to be present in your data structure as a string. You can convert the undefined values in your hash to the string `Nill` using the following code:

```
for (values %$hash) {
   $_ = 'Nill' if !defined($_);
}
```

---

If you meant you wanted `null` or `Null` (rather than `nill` or `Nill`), then you already have that. `~`, `null` and `Null` are equivalent. See section 10.3.2 of the aforelinked spec.